# sharepoint modal dialog events inside

Tags: sharepoint-online, modal-dialog, submit

i have a popup modal dialog on a sharepoint 2013 online site, inside it i want to have a submit button and a checkbox, if user checks it then the submit button is enabled. This code works except that nothing happens to the submit button. The submit button works if its not in the modal dialog.

This html code is inside my modal dialog:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="InformationBox" style="display:none;">
<div id="Div2" style="height:100px; padding-top:10px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;">

<label id="lblInformationMessage"> </label>
<br>
<img id="Picture" src=""/></img>
<div id="Div3" style="padding-right:5px;">

<p>i understand</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkme" />

<input type="submit" name="sendNewSms" class="inputButton" id="sendNewSms" value=" Send " />


</div>
</div>

</body>
<script>

var checker = document.getElementById('checkme');
var sendbtn = document.getElementById('sendNewSms');
 checker.onchange = function(){
if(this.checked == true){
    sendbtn.disabled = true;
} else {
    sendbtn.disabled = false;
}
  }
 </script>
 </html>

 var cloneModalContent = document.createElement('div'); 

                      $("#lblInformationMessage").html(newsArray[i].NewsText);

                           cloneModalContent.innerHTML =  document.getElementById('InformationBox').innerHTML;

                           var options = {
                               title: newsArray[i].Title,
                               autoSize: true,
                               html: cloneModalContent,
                               dialogReturnValueCallback:   myCallback,
                               allowMaximize: true,
                               showClose: true,
                               };
```

Comment: You have not attached any event to the submit button.What do you want to do on submit?

Comment: I want that the submit button is disabled and enabled if the user check the checkbox. It works on like js fiddle but not inside the modal dialog ...

Comment: Did you confirm that the onchange event is called.use alert or console.log inside the onchange function

Comment: ok i will check

Comment: Its not working, this is so annyoing

Comment: your script block is outside of body. Add it inside head tag and see.

Comment: Yes i have tryied that also of course

Comment: try the code given in my answer.May be the binding is not working bcoz it's not written inside window.load  and might be executed before document is loaded completely.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the modal dialog to close when the submit button is clicked, you'll need to apply some code to make it close the dialog.

```
<input type="submit" name="sendNewSms" class="inputButton" id="sendNewSms" value=" Send " onclick="function() { window.frameElement.commonModalDialogClose(1, ''); }" />
```

Comment: I have already made a callback like that, I want that the submit button is disabled and enabled if the user check the checkbox. It works on like js fiddle but not inside the modal dialog ...

Answer (score 0):

Try any of below methods:

Method 1:

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkme" onchange="EnableDisableButton(this);" />
```

And add below function:

```
 function EnableDisableButton(checker){
    var sendbtn = document.getElementById('sendNewSms');
sendbtn.disabled =checker.checked;

    }
```

Method 2:

```
      window.onload=function(){
        var checker = document.getElementById('checkme');

     checker.onchange = function(){
var sendbtn = document.getElementById('sendNewSms');
        sendbtn.disabled=this.checked;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That didnt worked either, i think @Dylan Cristy answear is right, sp 2013 destroys the elements id, so it will be null

Comment: @Jarule SharePoint does not destroy ids. If the element is having runat="server" property then sharepoint will append some extra text to the element id.But in your case the elements will be rendered with the same id(bcoz no runat=server).You can do one thing, use developer tools and check the id of the checkbox and button

Comment: Unnie is right, I did not notice that you didn't have the runat='server' property, and without that, the IDs should stay as you set them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this still happens in SP2013, but SP2010 will destroy your element IDs.  So I'd say your javascript is not working because `checker` and `sendbtn` are null, because after SharePoint renders the page, they no longer have the IDs you thought they did.

I would try something like this:

```
var checker = document.getElementById('<%= checkme.ClientID %>');
var sendbtn = document.getElementById('<%= sendNewSms.ClientID %>');
```

#### EDIT

Ok, since you can use jQuery, you can get this to work in the following way:

1. Add the `runat="server"` property to both of your input elements.
2. Move your whole script block up into a head section.
3. Use this as the script:

   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#<%= checkme.ClientID %>').change(function () {
           if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
               $('#<%= sendNewSms.ClientID %>').removeAttr('disabled');
           } else {
               $('#<%= sendNewSms.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
           }
       });
   });

[At the time of this edit, SPSE appears to not be formatting my code block as a code block.  Don't really know what's up with that.  Sorry if it looks messy.]

Comment: I think this is right, checking with firebug it says my elements are null, i will try your solution.

Comment: I tryied this but it said checker is null

Comment: Is it possible for you to use jQuery?  Or do you have to stick with straight Javascript?

Comment: I can use jquery, i have a ajax call by jquery now so its fine with jquery if you got some tip?

Comment: Ok, added a way to do it with jQuery, that definitely works for me (inside a modal dialog).  For some reason it seems like the code block is not formatting correctly though, don't know what to do about that.

Comment: Does it works for you?, becouse for me its not works. And its syntax error in your code, for <%=. I will choose a jquery popup instead, i cant work with html in sharepoints modal dialog

Comment: What I posted definitely works for me.  I don't use it to enable/disable a button, but I do use it to enable/disable another control, based on whether or not a checkbox is checked.  As for the syntax error, not sure why you are getting that. `<%=  %>` is completely valid ASP.NET.  Please see  this reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: okey, i removed the "# before <%=, thats why i got error. Okey, my code is retrieving information from a list, so users can post news and display them as a popup. The user can also specify witch sharepoint groups they want the popup be visible for. Maybe there something with my csom code. I dont know, but it works without the enable/disable functionality.

Comment: Well, `'#  '` is the jQuery selector for selecting an element by ID.  So what's happening there is, when you have `runat="server"` set on your control, `<%= yourControl.ClientID %>` also runs on the server and is replaced by the server generated client id, so that the jQuery `$('#serverGeneratedClientIdHere')` becomes a valid selector.  I use `$('#<%=myControl.ClientID%>')` all the time, and it works, so again I'm not sure why that would become a syntax error for you.

Comment: okey, well thank you for your answears and time. Yes its wierd. If you dont know, i use the html of the sp modal dialog, i edited my code so you can see how i building the modal dialog. Maybe there is something wrong there?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Usually when I make a page that I'll be using for a modal dialog, I base it off a blank SharePoint application page.  I've never really played around with making a SharePoint modal dialog with just vanilla HTML.  Also, I work with SP2010, and I'm not familiar with any differences there might be with SP2013.

Comment: Okey, well i checked in firebug now, and it says that the element was null. I tryied now with your tip of the <% and runat server, and now its not null and i can output an object!, now i just need to parse the json right?

Comment: Parse the json?  If you are successfully getting the elements, I would say to try the jQuery code I posted...

Comment: Yes i just wanted to see what the output was. Anyway, i tryied with your code, and after i have checked the checkbox i must refresh the page for it to work. Do i need a Postback or something ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14215/discussion-between-dylan-cristy-and-jarule)